# Android Studio underlying data structure for dominoes

Tags: java, android, arrays, data-structures

I am currently in the process of trying to develop "Dominoes" the game, in android studio. What I am concerned about is how the board(grid) would work, and as this is my first time creating a game, I have no idea what kind of data structure I should use.

- The game has 28 dominoes
- Each domino has two sides

Yes, there are a lot of other aspects to this assignment that need to go into consideration, but as for right now, I am only concerned with how the board will work with the dominoes.

The reason I need a underlying data structure for this project is because this game is going to be online, so we need to be able to store the information of where the tiles are and send that information over to the other user.

My initial thoughts were a 2D array. A 2D array would work if the board was a fixed size, and each index in the array has a value and each domino is assigned that value when placed on board. But im not sure how that would work with sending the data to a database? I would be sending the entire 2D array when all I want to send would be the specific tiles that are currently placed on the screen.

My second thoughts for this would be a map that stores the index of where the tile is placed, and also stores a domino object. This way we can only send the map to the database, and don't have to send a bunch of empty information that slows down the game and creates unnessary traffic. But the problem with this idea is that if I use a map, I don't know how I would index each domino and how they would correspond to an index on the board?

Anyways, Im sure there are a lot of easier more straightforward ways to approach this idea and I'm curious to know what methods someone who has created board games with underlying data structures would use. Any help or guidance on how to get started would be highly appreciated!